# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/installreferrer/api/InstallReferrerStateListener; error

Tags: android, xamarin, branch.io

Please, help me to understand and fix next error, that occurs on my application startup.

```
12-24 09:50:21.073 16050-16050/com.dev.ct.dev I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.branch.referral.InstallListener$ReferrerClientWrapper$1>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/installreferrer/api/InstallReferrerStateListener;
    at void io.branch.referral.InstallListener.captureInstallReferrer(android.content.Context, long, io.branch.referral.InstallListener$IInstallReferrerEvents) (InstallListener.java:54)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.registerAppInit(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, io.branch.referral.ServerRequest$PROCESS_WAIT_LOCK) (Branch.java:2322)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener) (Branch.java:2280)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, android.app.Activity, boolean) (Branch.java:1269)
    at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:931)
    at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener) (Branch.java:894)
    at void mobile.droid.ctrader.infrastructure.DroidApplication.n_onCreate() (DroidApplication.java:-2)
    at void mobile.droid.ctrader.infrastructure.DroidApplication.onCreate() (DroidApplication.java:27)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1032)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5876)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1699)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerStateListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dev.ct.dev-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dev.ct.dev-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.dev.ct.dev-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at void io.branch.referral.InstallListener.captureInstallReferrer(android.content.Context, long, io.branch.referral.InstallListener$IInstallReferrerEvents) (InstallListener.java:54)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.registerAppInit(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, io.branch.referral.ServerRequest$PROCESS_WAIT_LOCK) (Branch.java:2322)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener) (Branch.java:2280)
    at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, android.app.Activity, boolean) (Branch.java:1269)
    at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener, android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:931)
    at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener) (Branch.java:894)
    at void mobile.droid.ctrader.infrastructure.DroidApplication.n_onCreate() (DroidApplication.java:-2)12-24 09:50:21.074 16050-16050/com.dev.ct.dev I/art:
    at void mobile.droid.ctrader.infrastructure.DroidApplication.onCreate() (DroidApplication.java:27)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1032)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5876)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1699)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

This is a c# xamarin code, that runs at activity OnStart

```
        BranchAndroid.GetAutoInstance(ApplicationContext.Instance);
        BranchAndroid.Init(activity, "SOME_KEY", new BranchSessionListener()); // This line fails
        BranchXamarinSDK.Branch.GetInstance().SetMaxRetries(5);
```

BranchSessionListener is just a custom c# class that implements InitSessionComplete method.

I don't know correct way to fix this issue. Please, help

Comment: Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I'm hitting the exact same issue

Comment: Update: I applied a factory reset on the emulator and the issue was gone. On a device this error never happened.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin, you will need to initialize Branch in the onCreate of your MainActivity. Please refer to our detailed Xamarin Test Bed application code for Android for help on initial integration steps:

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Examples/droid_example/Branch_Testbed_Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Hi Joon, I'm having the exact same issue and my configuration matches the sample provided. We are using v5.0.4. Any ideas or previous reports for the same issue?